# How to serialize a generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics, serialization

I have started to read about serialization in Java and little bit in other languages too, but what if I have a generic class and I want to save a instance of it to file.

code example

```
public class Generic<T> {
  private T key;
  public Generic<T>() {
    key = null;
  }
  public Generic<T>(T key) {
    this.key = key;
  }
}
```

Whats the best way to save this kind of Object? (Of course there is more in my real ceneric class, but I'm just wondering the actual idea.)

Comment: Just as any other class: make it implement the `Serializable` interface `:)`

Comment: @sp00m: sometimes it is not possible to change the class. Probably not the case here ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You **need** to make generic class `Serializable` as usual.

`public class Generic<T> implements Serializable {...}`

If fields are declared using generic types, you **may want** to specify that they should implement `Serializable`.

`public class Generic<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {...}`

Please be aware of uncommon Java syntax here.

`public class Generic<T extends Something & Serializable> implements Serializable {...}`

Comment: Ty I prefer this answer because it's easier to me to add this thing to my class... I have it allready ... implements serializable, but when I try ObjectOutputStream to save. My program just freezes.

Comment: Implementing `Serializable` breaks encapsulation and information hiding; all private and package-private members become part of the class's exported API.  This introduces potential security vulnerabilities and may make the class more fragile.  The decision to implement `Serializable` should be made with great care and the serialized form should be carefully designed (Efffective Java, 2nd Ed).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want (or cannot) implement the Serializable interface, you can use XStream. Here is a short [tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

In your case:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
Generic<T> generic = ...;//whatever needed
String xml = xstream.toXML(generic);
//write it to a file (or use xstream directly to write it to a file)
```

Comment: Another alternative to implementing `Serializable` is to implement `Externalizable` (which itself extends `Serializable`).