# Static method with parameter that must implement Serializable

Tags: java, generics, encryption, serialization

I've made an `Encryption` class with a static method like so...

```
public static SealedObject encrypt(Object toEncrypt)
```

I'd like to use the `encrypt` method statically as a helper function. The problem is that when creating the `SealedObject` to return (after encrypting the supplied `Object` with a cipher) the `SealedObject` requires the supplied `Object` to implement `Serializable`. Which `Object` itself doesn't implement.

Since the `encrypt` method takes an `Object`, it doesn't implement `Serializable` so I can't create the `SealedObject` to return from the supplied `Object`.

How can I use generics to ensure the parameter passed implements `Serializable` but still keeping the static nature of the method?

The method will be used on many different types

Comment: Why don't you specify `public static SealedObject encrypt(Serializable toEncrypt)`?

Comment: I think this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16852247/2193236

Comment: @JamesKPolk Wow I never thought of that. OO languages are great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough. Just use type bounds on a method.

```
public <T extends Serializable> SealedObject encrypt(T object) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    return new SealedObject(object, null);
}
```